# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - web.config issue

Tags: php, http, iis, iis-8.5

I get this error when im trying to go to localhost, and i want the index.php to show up.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXTbD.png

This is my web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3">
                    <match url="^(.*)\.htm$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 4">
                    <match url="^(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="login.php?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 5">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="login.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer> </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 0 means you forgot to download and install IIS URL Rewrite module from Microsoft.